# How do I get a list of gems that are installed that have native extensions?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm on windows, and have updated from ruby 1.8.x to 1.9.x, and am now getting error popups that complain ruby-mssomethingrt.1.8.x.dll is missing.

I would like to find out which gems have native extensions, so I can uninstall them and force a rebuild of the native extensions locally during installation again, to make the error go away.

Comment: +1 Very useful after an OS distribution upgrade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good start would be to look at the gem specification for each gem and see if it has the [extensions](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#extensions) field set. That should leave you with a short-list of gems to re-install. They don't necessarily all use native extensions, but if you look at the corresponding `extconf.rb` files, this should be pretty easy to find out.

Update: Here is a short ruby script to list those gems:

```
require 'rubygems'

Gem.source_index.each do |gem|
  spec =  Gem.source_index.specification(gem[0])
  ext = spec.extensions
  puts "#{gem[0]} has extensions: #{ext}" unless ext.empty?
end
```

Comment: This answer is definitely better than nothing (marking it +1). But indeed it would seem natural that the gem command had such a feature...

Comment: Now, unfortunately, `Gem.source_index` seems to be gone.

Answer (score 9):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5167272/770517), here is a solution that finds and offers to reinstall gems with native extensions **that works with recent rubies (>=1.9)**.

```
native_gems = []
Gem::Specification.each do |spec|
  native_gems << "#{spec.name}:#{spec.version}" unless spec.extensions.empty?
end

install_cmd = "gem install #{native_gems.join ' '}"
puts "Found #{native_gems.length} gem(s) with native extensions:"
puts "\n> " + install_cmd, "\nReinstall gems with above command? (yn)"

exec insall_cmd if gets.downcase[0] == 'y'
```

Example Output:

```
Found 36 gem(s) with native extensions:

> gem install atomic:1.1.13 bcrypt-ruby:3.0.1 bigdecimal:1.2.0 eventmachine:1.0.3 eventmachine:1.0.0 eventmachine:0.12.10 ffi:1.9.3 ffi:1.9.0 ffi:1.7.0 hiredis:0.4.5 hpricot:0.8.6 io-console:0.4.2 json:1.8.1 json:1.8.0 json:1.7.6 nokogiri:1.6.0 nokogiri:1.5.9 pg:0.17.1 pg:0.17.0 pg:0.16.0 pg:0.15.1 pg:0.13.2 psych:2.0.0 puma:2.7.1 puma:2.6.0 puma:2.4.0 puma:1.6.3 sqlite3:1.3.8 sqlite3:1.3.7 sqlite3:1.3.5 therubyracer:0.12.0 thin:1.5.1 thin:1.5.0 thin:1.4.1 websocket-driver:0.2.3 websocket-driver:0.1.0

Reinstall gems with above command? (yn)
…
```

Comment: This answer should be preferred by anyone working with a modern version of Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

You can rebuild (and restore to a pristine state) all installed gems with:

```
gem pristine --all
```

`--all --no-extensions` will restore gems *without* extensions, but despite being documented, `--extensions` appears to have no effect (at least on rubygems 1.8.23 on Ubuntu 12.10).

Comment: This command is covernig too many gems (including the ones without native extension), but that doesn't hurt. It does the job and then some...

Comment: also answers another question I've had … "if I modify a gem for debugging, how can I reliably restore it?"

Comment: `gem pristine` doesn't actually recompile any gems, even the gems with native extensions.

Comment: Despite being documented? Unless documentation changed, it's not supposed to have an effect, it's including natively extended gems by default. There's no documented way to isolate them. --- @MarkDBlackwell What dou you mean? Gems without native extensions don't need to be compiled (it's just ruby), and the ones that do, will actually reconfigure and recompile from scratch, which is exactly what `gem pristine` is supposed to do. :-) Docs say: `All extensions are rebuilt and all bin stubs for the gem are regenerated`

Answer (score 2):

Onliner for bundler + rails:

```
rails r "puts Gem::Specification.select{|i| i.extensions.any?}.map(&:name)"
```

prints out all native code gems (which usually need updates when updating major Ruby versions)

Answer (score 1):

In Cygwin you could try `gem list --all -d | grep --before-context=1 --after-context=4 Platform`.

Comment: `gem list` also works for mac

Answer (score 0):

gem list

the part after the version next to the gem should indicate whether it's running native code:
e.g. json (1.4.6 x86-mingw32)

The error you are seeing is because one of the gems you are using expects the 1.8 ruby interpreter to be present which it no longer is (as you have upgraded to 1.9).

I would have thought that just running 'gem update' would fix your problem. If it doesn't, then you might need to seek an alternative gem for the one that is expecting the ruby 1.8 interpreter to be present.

Comment: what version of rubygems? 1.3.7 shows the json gem like this: `json (1.6.5)` (no platform info)

Comment: This lists gems that bundle pre-built extensions, but does not include those that build them from source only.