# How to determine a gem is native?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do I know that a gem need to be installed as native by providing `--platform=ruby` at the time of installation?

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165950/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-gems-that-are-installed-that-have-native-extensions

Comment: yes..but I want to know before installing a gem

Answer (score 0):

## Checking if a gem uses native extensions before installation

To download the gem use the command:

`gem fetch <gem_name>`

This will download the gem into your current working directory. 
To extract the source code for the gem use the command:

`gem unpack <gem_name>`

This will extract the gem to your current working directory.

Then inspect the source code for the gem to see if it has an `ext` directory. If so, it likely has native extensions. You can then proceed with installation.